# Error when publishing .net core app "no startup configured "

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

since two days an error occured when i'm publishing my .net core app on IIS.
My angular part is working well but the .net core part do not load.

In my Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddCors();
        services.AddDbContext<HistoriqueContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("HistoriqueContext"), b => b.UseRowNumberForPaging()));
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseCors(builder => builder
        .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowCredentials());
        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            await next();
            if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404 && !Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value))
            {
                context.Request.Path = "/index.html";
                await next();
            }
        });

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        //app.UseCorsMiddleware();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

In my Program.cs:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();          
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

The log when in file://servername/appcore/logs/:

```
Application startup exception: System.InvalidOperationException: No startup configured. Please specify startup via WebHostBuilder.UseStartup, WebHostBuilder.Configure, injecting IStartup or specifying the startup assembly via StartupAssemblyKey in the web host configuration.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureStartup()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureApplicationServices()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.Initialize()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\DSMHistory
Now listening on: http://127.0.0.1:38556
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
Application is shutting down...
```

Comment: try debugging it locally line by line in the startup.cs and see which service is having an exception and add it to your question

Comment: all works locally :/

Comment: How did you publish your project? Does issue exsit when you create and publish a new default mvc template?

Comment: Hi @Q.Rey, how you resolved the error, please give the answer. I have 2 pc, in one its running find in local, but getting the error in another pc.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Hosting/Hosting/src/Internal/WebHost.cs#L202 So the `IStartup` service wasn't created?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it turned out that I had a method call happening in the Startup.cs constructor that was throwing an exception and resulting in this exact error.